# Can git urls have a query string?

Tags: git, url

Is it possible / common place / discouraged for git urls (of any kind) to have query strings?

I am considering to store tag and branch information as query string parameter like so:

```
<protocol>:<path>?branch=<branch>&tag=<tag>

# Concrete example:

https://github.com/back2dos/somelib?branch=develop&tag=2.3.0
```

I would extract these parameters before passing the url to git, so I do NOT intend to pass query strings to git (unless other parameters are left after extraction).

I haven't yet seen git urls using query strings at all, so I feel I'm on the safe side. Still I wonder how likely this is to backfire because somebody needs precisely these parameters? Is it any safer if I use `#` instead of `?` to separate the parameters from the actual url?

Comment: It’s just an URL; you can do whatever you want with it…

Comment: I know I can do whatever I want. I would like to know more about the likelihood of certain implications of what I choose to do.

Answer (score 3):

If the URL is meant to be viewed through a browser, then query strings may be commonplace. If you are storing a URL in a database, and then application code extracts branch and tag info from the query string before cloning or pulling, then you are running the risk that the whole URL will get passed inadvertently to `git clone`. At that point Git has its own error handling in place and should intelligently complain that the URL does not adhere to one of the Git protocols.

The "?" in the query string is usually an invalid character for a file name, so without giving the name of the folder to clone into, the `git clone` operation will fail.

Using one of my own Git repos, I tried this command and got the following response:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/foo/bar?branch=baz bar
Cloning into 'bar'...
fatal: https://github.com/foo/bar?branch=baz/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

So it looks like Git assumes a certain folder structure on the remote, and doesn't intelligently handle the query string.